# Route forwarding with Express.io

Tags: express, socket.io

I try to forward a route using Express.io but it doesn't work, I read the doc on Github and I did exactly as they say. I don't know where is the issue...

```
app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    me.pseudo = req.body.pseudo;
    me.email = req.body.email;
    me.gravatar = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + md5(me.email) + "?s=140";
    users.push(me);
    req.io.route('hello'); //error here
});

app.io.route('hello', function(req) {
   console.log('Done !'); 
});
```

Errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'route' of undefined
    at /Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Tchat-Express/app.js:78:12
```

Comment: I would start by doing a console.log on the app.io and the req.io to see if they exist where you expect them too. What line is line 78?

Comment: Could also `util = require("util");` at the top and do `console.log(util.inspect(req));` inside of app.post. It should show the members and properties of `req` object. Which should give good insight. Obviously above where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for app.io, but usually when you need to share same function between routes, you either 
**a) make the error handler a separate function and call it from multiple routes:**

```
function handleError(req, res) {
  //handle error
}

app.post('/foo', function(req, res) {
  //if conditions are met, else
  handleError(req, res); 
});
```

**b) abstract further by making a module:**

```
//user.js
module.exports = {
  signin: function(req, res) {},
  signinError: function(req, res) {},
};
```

Routing Code

```
//routes.js
var user = require('../modules/user');

app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
  //validate signin
  //else
  user.signinError(req, res);
});

app.post('/signin-no-error', user.signin);
```